# Cannot build squid3 with dpkg -i *.deb

Tags: dependencies, raspberry-pi3

trying to build my own squid3 on Raspberrypi

dpkg -i *.deb

Any suggestions how to solve the dependency problems - leaving unconfigured issue?

But it stops after a while:

```html
(Reading database ... 37935 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack squid3_3.4.8-6+deb8u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking squid3 (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) over (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Preparing to unpack squid3-common_3.4.8-6+deb8u4_all.deb ...
Unpacking squid3-common (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) over (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Preparing to unpack squid3-dbg_3.4.8-6+deb8u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking squid3-dbg (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) over (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Preparing to unpack squid-cgi_3.4.8-6+deb8u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking squid-cgi (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) over (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Preparing to unpack squidclient_3.4.8-6+deb8u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking squidclient (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) over (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Preparing to unpack squid-purge_3.4.8-6+deb8u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking squid-purge (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) over (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of squid3:
 squid3 depends on logrotate (>= 3.5.4-1); however:
  Package logrotate is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package squid3 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up squid3-common (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of squid3-dbg:
 squid3-dbg depends on squid3 (= 3.4.8-6+deb8u4); however:
  Package squid3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package squid3-dbg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up squid-cgi (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Setting up squidclient (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Setting up squid-purge (3.4.8-6+deb8u4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squid3
 squid3-dbg
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need those dependencies and dpkg is not going to install those for you. On a Raspberry PI you normally have access to the package manager `apt`. If your sources are configured correctly, you can just run:

```
apt-get install squid3
```

Comment: Thanks! But I build my own Squid with SSL. I dunno want to use the default squid.